# Docker Alpine Latext texmf-dist styles not found

Tags: docker, latex, pandoc, alpine-linux

I'm attempting to add some necessary latext style files to the `pandoc/latex` docker container (which itself is built over Alpine) and the underlying latex to pdf conversion does is unable to find some of the style files I've added. Here's my Dockerfile, which adds the packages I need.

```
FROM pandoc/latex:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add texlive-xetex texmf-dist-pictures texmf-dist-latexextra poppler-utils && texhash
```

I can see that the style file I need is installed.

```
$ docker run --rm -it --entrypoint /bin/sh -v $PWD:/data mypandoc:latest 
/data # find / -name tikzpagenodes.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tikzpagenodes/tikzpagenodes.sty
```

But, when I try to do the actual build, I get the following error.

```
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: File `tikzpagenodes.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.103 \usepackage
```

I had hoped that the call to `texhash` in the container build would fix this, but it did not. Is there some trick to getting the `texmf-dist` directories into the search path? The problem appears to be with all of the styles I've added from `texmf-dist`, not just this one. Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered asking on https://tex.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `tlmgr` from TeXLive to install more packages. The `pandoc/latex` Docker container does not use the TeX installation from Alpine in order to give users more flexibility and to reduce image size – the Alpine packages are far less fine-grained.

Usually, one will add the following to the Dockerfile

```
# Install additional LaTeX packages
RUN tlmgr update --self && tlmgr install \
  pgf # <list of packages goes here>
```

Alternatively, you could use the `pandoc/core` image and build your own LaTeX container using the Alpine system packages.

Comment: Thanks. Using `tlmgr` rather than Alpine packages ended up fixing this. It turns out that the packages install to a different location than the latex installation in the container.